# how to find if session has expired in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, session-cookies

I have to code this scenario:

Some user comes to fill a form and while user is at it, session expires;
User tries to submit form, as session has expired it will take him to login page after which he is rediredted to form page with a prefilled form with data he filled previously.

my propsed solution:
on form submit, check if user session is expired with an ajax call, if yes, drop a cookie with values of filled form, user comes back to same form, prefill the form from cookie value.

how far I got:
not much; I used ajax call to check session expiry with a backend call to this function:

```
def check_valid_session(request):
    session_expiry_date = request.session.get_expiry_date()
    now = datetime.now()
    seconds_left = (session_expiry_date - now).total_seconds()
    if seconds_left <= 0:
        return JsonResponse({'session_expired': True, 'seconds_left': seconds_left })
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'session_expired':False, 'seconds_left': seconds_left})
```

in my settings I have:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "sso-sessionid"
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10 
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.mydomain.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

but in response, I always get seconds_left as something close to 9.999.
and session_expiry_date keeps increasing itself by 10 seconds each time i hit submit and call the backend code above.
How to get correct session expire time? any alternative approach?

Comment: Did you figure out how to find if a session has expired? 
request.session.get_expiry_age() -- doesnt actually return how many seconds left before session expires. It only gives  what we set in request.session.set_expiry(10).

Answer (score 2):

So what is happening here is that the continuous requests to your check_valid_session view are refreshing the cookie's age to 10 seconds from the last request as it should. The cookie will only expire when it has been in your case 10 seconds since the last request.

Because you have to make a request to get the cookies expiry this will return some value close to 10 every time.

As for the problem of saving the users data with a cookie if their session has expired. How will you know what user is making the request if there is no session data? The only thing you could do that i can think of is to somehow save their post data with their associated ip address. Although this is definitely over complicating the problem and would not be good from a security point of view as it would be possible for other users to see this post data if they made a request with the same ip.

The simplest solution to this is to just increase the timeout for the session. 10 seconds is incredibly short, the default value for SESSION_COOKIE_AGE is 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

Which will save the sessions to the database with every request. Also the cookie will be sent with every request.